# Applying AddThis buttons

Tags: html, addthis, social-media, sharethis

I want to add AddThis, social bookmarking service, to my site. I followed the instruction on the site. There is an option where you can select your own services and customize the order.

[image]

I selected facebook, twitter, google, linked in, pinterest and whatsapp.

As instructed, I added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-53353be15c66b7b4" async="async"></script>
```

inside the head tag just before closing.

Then, where I need the buttons to show, I added

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_5"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_6"></a>
</div>
```

The end result:

[image]

It shows a few buttons that I haven't selected.

I must be doing something wrong and spent the whole day looking into it. Can you help.

Comment: Are you testing this locally? I've had some issues with testing AddThis locally. Try adding it to a live site, clearing your cache and see what the result is. Also try an *incognito*/*private* tab. (Protip for disabling cache in a jiffy.)

Comment: also make sure u have any adblocking extensions disabled.

Comment: @BramVanroy, on Xamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Not Seeing the Buttons You Expected? It’s Because Smart Layers are Personalized
>
> One of the key features of our new Smart Layers is something you can’t
>   actually see. All the share buttons are personalized to each visitor.
>   This makes it much more likely that people will share your site.
>
> -**source: http://www.addthis.com/blog/2013/07/30/not-seeing-the-buttons-you-want/**

So basically what it means is that if a particular user is know to use a particular social service more, only those buttons will be shown to that person. Filtering appears to be done at a low level.

---

Have a look at [other similar services](http://www.rkresponsivedesign.com/5-free-social-sharing-plugin-alternatives-shareaholic/).

Comment: Considering that that posts dates back to 2013 and a lot of people have uttered their discomfort with this, I highly doubt that addThis is still using this method.

Comment: scroll down to comments section, there's a 2 month old comment confirming this.

Comment: I am not sure, since it is implemented at the *domain* level. You could always make your own custom buttons if you are up for it or use some other service.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are manually setting the icons on your page. Considering you are selecting your services via the addthis.com website, simply add the following div element to your page, in place of your current addthis code:

```
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
```

That div will get filled automatically with the services you selected from addthis.com, trust me on this one I got this.

Comment: I did replace the code with <div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div> and it shows blank (nothing) now.

Comment: Try moving your javascript file to the end of the page, right before the closing </body> tag.

Also, make sure you hit activate on the addthis.com website. And that your addthis.com profile using the services matches the profile you are using on your website ex. your user id is: ra-53353be15c66b7b4

Comment: did delete histoy and cache, refreshed it. It shows share buttons but the problem persist. Selected service not being shown, yet.

Comment: So you tried just this:

    <div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-53353be15c66b7b4" async="async"></script>

and it's still not working? The fact that it's showing buttons for other services leads me to believe you might have the wrong publisher id on your site or it's somehow getting populated automatically and not taking into consideration your manually selected services. You should contact addthis.com support. They are great!

Answer (score 1):

I am Elsa from the AddThis support team.

If you were using the default AddThis configuration it's using what we call Preferred Services. These are different for each individual based on their past sharing history and what services are most popular in our service. This is designed to make it easy for users to share to their preferred service and to increase sharing.

If you want to show up the dashboard configured sharing button in your website then Replace the below code

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_5"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_6"></a>
</div>
```

with the below inline HTML code of that tool.

```
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
```

Comment: I need facebook, twitter, google, linked in, pinterest and whatsapp for every user. Will replacing the code help?

Comment: @DakshBathla this is exactly the same thing that I pointed out ;-). Do remember to accept the best answer.

Comment: @Ashesh, if its true, as pointed out by you and Elsa George, I hardly understand why give your client an option to choose service from when it will not be implemented. Accepted your answer.

Comment: I think there are no more "ifs", this is a classic case of service provider trying to act smart but actually causing problems to their users.

Comment: Elsa, can you confirm the documentation on addthis about customizing your buttons is outdated then ? adding stuff like `<a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>` doesnt do a thing anymore. It looks like you always have to create a profile for each client.